# Geth 1.5.8 only returns 0

Tags: go-ethereum

I updated from 1.5.7 to 1.5.8 and now all my functions return 0.

Before you ask, yes the functions I am calling don't modifier the blockchain.

I tested both my contract and this simpleStorage code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;

contract simpleStorage {
    uint storedData = 4;

    function set(uint x) {
        storedData = x;
    }

    function get() constant returns (uint retVal) {
        return storedData;
    }
}
```

Here is my geth command:

```
geth --dev --mine --rpc --rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir dev
```

The **get()** function should return 4, but it always returns 0 in versions 1.5.8 and 1.5.9

Works perfectly fine in 1.5.7 with the same compiler version.

Same results in both Linux and Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Remix - Internal JavaScript VM - Good Result

Here's a screenshot of Remix (Browser Solidity) showing that your contract works as expected:

[image]

### Remix - `geth` RPC - Bad Result

Here's a screenshot of Remix showing that your contract does not work as expected when deploying to a `geth` 1.5.9 dev blockchain using the parameters you specified in your question.

### `geth` 1.5.9 Command Line - Good Result

I flattened the following code and assigned it to a variable:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;

contract SimpleStorage {
    uint storedData = 4;

    function set(uint x) {
        storedData = x;
    }

    function get() constant returns (uint retVal) {
        return storedData;
    }
}
```

And ran the following commands in the `geth` console:

```
var simpleStorageSource='pragma solidity ^0.4.2;contract SimpleStorage { uint storedData = 4; function set(uint x) { storedData = x; } function get() constant returns (uint retVal) { return storedData; }}'

var simpleStorageCompiled=web3.eth.compile.solidity(simpleStorageSource);

var simpleStorageContract = web3.eth.contract(simpleStorageCompiled['<stdin>:SimpleStorage'].info.abiDefinition);

var simpleStorage = simpleStorageContract.new({
    from: web3.eth.accounts[0],
    data: simpleStorageCompiled['<stdin>:SimpleStorage'].code, gas: 400000},
    function(e, contract) {
      if (!e) {
        if (!contract.address) {
          console.log("Contract transaction send: TransactionHash: " +
            contract.transactionHash + " waiting to be mined...");
        } else {
          console.log("Contract mined! Address: " + contract.address);
          console.log(contract);
        }
    }
});

Contract transaction send: TransactionHash: 0x45c230b92d8a41c16b74b078323e7fa6e59b07e67bb6e017ac72020a4bf4534c waiting to be mined...

Contract mined! Address: 0x9682c4a5e47a4f61c03118e8bba3de2d203a256c

> simpleStorage.get()
4
```

It seems the problem may be in Remix. You may want to file a bug report in the Remix repository.

@RolandKofler suggested that the problem could be in `geth`'s JSON-RPC API.

Comment: I guess I will stick with 1.5.7 for now and file a bug report. Thanks for the help!